# How to get latest timestamp in a column?

Tags: python, django

I have a timestamp column in my t1 table. The format is as: `2009-12-24 06:17:34`

There are many entries as such.

How do we query from views to get the latest timestamp

Comment: Are you using a django model with a DateTime field? Or is this something else? Show what code you are using and we can help you better.

Comment: Yes i am using a django model with a DateTime field.
so in my models.py i have this 
class A...
....
mod_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=True)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ModelClass.objects.latest(timestamp_field)
```